# CREATE TABLE SQL statement won't run

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to run this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE 'score_table' 
(
  'name' text NOT NULL, 
  'email' text NOT NULL, 
  'company' text NOT NULL, 
  'score_total' bigint(11) NOT NULL, 
  'score_string' longtext NOT NULL, 
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  'date' timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id') 
) 
ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near ''score_table' 
('name' text NOT NULL, 'email' text NOT NULL, 'company' text NOT N' at line 1
```

And I have no idea what's wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Enough answers are given so i want to make a remark: You really overuse the quotation marks. You don't have to use them unless the name also doubles as a keyword. See: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the responses everyone! Stack overflow is king ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table and field names need to be put in backticks instead of single quotes (or no quotes at all):

```
CREATE TABLE `score_table`.....
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't enclose your table name in single quotes like that.

```
    CREATE TABLE `score_table` (`name` text NOT NULL, `email` text NOT NULL, `company` text NOT NULL, `score_total` bigint(11) NOT NULL, `score_string` longtext NOT NULL, `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks and not single quotes:

Your SQL statement should be:

```
CREATE TABLE score_table ( 
    `name` text NOT NULL, 
    `email` text NOT NULL, 
    `company` text NOT NULL, 
    `score_total` bigint(11) NOT NULL, 
    `score_string` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) 
ENGINE= MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier table name and field names must not be in Quotes so avoid them i edited your query try this and also, if you are using Magic Quotes avoid using them as well(just avoid Magic quotes in your current scenario to find if you are doing it all correct.)

```
CREATE TABLE score_table (name text NOT NULL, email text NOT NULL, company text NOT NULL, score_total bigint(11) NOT NULL, score_string longtext NOT NULL, id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, date timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY  (id) ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```